# ASP:NET Confirm Password field

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Im creating a simple registration form in asp.net. 
Here's my problem:
If my confirm passwordfield is empty it still submits the form. I'm using compareToValidate do I also need to use a requiredvalidator. I'm new to asp.net but shouldnt the comparevalidator generate an error if lets say password is 123 and the confirmpassword is empty.

```
        <fieldset>
       <legend>Enter your data</legend>
       <table>
        <tr>
       <td align="right">User Name :</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td align="left">
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbUsername" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvUserName" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="tbUsername" 
        CssClass="ValidationError"
        ErrorMessage="&laquo; (Required)"
        ToolTip="User Name is a REQUIRED field"
        ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
</tr>`enter code here`
<tr >
<td align="right">Password&nbsp;:&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="left"> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
     ErrorMessage="&laquo; (Required)" 
     ControlToValidate="tbPassword"
     CssClass="ValidationError"

    ToolTip="Password is a REQUIRED field"
    ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</td>

</tr>
<tr >
<td align="right">Confirm Password&nbsp;:&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="left"> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPass" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" 
     ControlToValidate="ConfirmPass"
     CssClass="ValidationError"
     ControlToCompare="tbPassword"
     ErrorMessage="No Match" 
     ToolTip="Password must be the same" />

</td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You must provide a required validator as well! Compare validator will only compare the value with the target control and alert the user.

```
<td align="left"> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPass" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" 
     ControlToValidate="ConfirmPass"
     CssClass="ValidationError"
     ControlToCompare="tbPassword"
     ErrorMessage="No Match" 
     ToolTip="Password must be the same" />

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
     ErrorMessage="&laquo; (Required)" 
     ControlToValidate="ConfirmPass"
     CssClass="ValidationError"
     ToolTip="Compare Password is a REQUIRED field">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</td>
```

Hopes this help you!

Comment: A tooltip on a validator, when they are not visible until the error has occurred, is a bit pointless don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO that exactly what it is supposed to do. The CompareValidator control is used to compare the value of one input control to the value of another input control or to a fixed value.

If the input control is empty, no validation functions are called and validation succeeds. Use a RequiredFieldValidator control to prevent the user from skipping an input control.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db330ayw(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

**Simple Method**
Its really working
                        `<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ID="Comp1" ControlToValidate="tbPassword" ControlToCompare="ConfirmPass" Text="Password mismatch" Font-Size="11px" ForeColor="Red"  />`